# Как спарсить картинку с сайта?

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

Получаю: **TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'ResultSet'**

Как я парсю:

```
def get_img(filt1 = "nedvizhimost", filt2 = "doma"):
    response = requests.get(url = f"https://www.olx.ua/{filt1}/{filt2}/?search%5Border%5D=created_at%3Adesc", allow_redirects=True)
    html = BS(response.content, 'lxml')
    img = html.select('tbody > tr > td.photo-cell > a > img')
    
    for i in range(5, 44):
        with open(f"{i}.png", "wb") as file:
            file.write(img)
```

Структура сайта:

```
<td class="photo-cell" rowspan="2" width="150">
  <a class="thumb vtop inlblk rel tdnone linkWithHash linkWithHashPromoted scale4 detailsLink" href="https://www.olx.ua/d/obyavlenie/prodam-noviy-1-pov-budinok-poltava-m-n-polovki-pr-svtankoviy-11-IDMFnxs.html#8fe627080c;promoted" title="">
      <img alt="Продам новий 1-пов. будинок. Полтава, м-н Половки, пр. Світанковий 11" class="fleft" src="https://ireland.apollo.olxcdn.com:443/v1/files/jwyj76wbqpkb-UA/image;s=644x461"/>
      <span class="inlblk icon paid type2 abs zi2" title="ТОП"></span>
  </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как тривиальный пример

```
import urllib.request

url = "Сюда втыкаешь спарсеный урл картинки"
img = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

with open("img.jpg", "wb") as output:
    out.write(img)
```